# Small view displaying data in real-time on multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I would like to create a small view under my navigation bar where i would display statistics based on the user utilisation of my app and those statistics could evolve in real-time. 
I want to be able to "inject" this small view in lot of different views from my app just under the navigation bar.

I don't know how to proceed to create this small view that can use in different bigger views. And how i can interact with this view and others.

I read and tried things concerning xib files, but not sure i'm going in the right direction. 
I'm thinking of using containers view but i'm not sure i can be able to "re-use" it in another view. 
I'm a bit lost and i would like some guidance on how to make that in the best and flexible way.

Edit: I'have been trying with containers view. Here is what i did for the moment, i don't know if it's the right/best method.
[image: ContainerMethod]

In my two main view controller i got a container who embed the small view container where i'm gonna put my statistics.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path with containers.

I suggest creating a view controller that has the view you want always displayed and a container view that takes up the rest of the screen space.  This is your container view controller.

Each other view that you want to show inside the container area would be managed by a child view controller.  This way, the controller with the most-persistent view is the parent of the ones that change.

Comment: That's kind of what i'm trying right now, i just created container views in all the views where i want my small view, and i ctrl-dragged to a view controller with my small view inside to embed it in the container views, i don't know if it's really clear... i'm kind of confuse also.

Comment: I think I'm suggesting the opposite.  Have only one instance of your small view.  Have it managed by a controller.  Make other controllers owned by that one and show their views in the parent's container area.